# Create and bind SSL certificate in WIX setup project

Tags: wcf, wix, wix3.5

How can I create SSL certificate and bind that certificate to my WCF Rest service hosted as Windows Service in WIX Setup Installer?

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 options on my mind :
1. Harvest the certificate with heat and then with custom action bind it to your WCF
2.Add the certificate to your Custom action project resources as embedded file , write it to selected directory with your custom action and then bind it to your WCF

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am already done with the it. I have a question now, I will be installing my WCF Service on multiple servers for different clients. What kind of SSL certificate can i use? Should I have to buy certificate for every server?

Comment: If its for testing you can just use self signed certs , but for real customers you have to buy a real one .Any certificate can be installed on multiple servers.You can also check this .https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1216451-securing-multiple-servers---ssl-certificates